# Code that increases transaction log based on actual size of transaction log. Problem with assigning the size as a variable

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server 2019 database with a 300GB transaction log file. I want to automatically manage the transaction log file size with a job to prevent it from expanding automatically during peak hours.

My approach is to increase transaction log file size by 20% at night when available log space is less than 10%.

The example is based on AdventureWorks2019 database.

```
DECLARE @logSizeMB INT
DECLARE @logFreeSpace_mb INT
DECLARE @logIncrementPercent INT
DECLARE @newSize INT

-- Get current size in MB
SELECT @logSizeMB = size/128 FROM sys.database_files WHERE type_desc = 'LOG'

-- Get free space  in MB
SELECT @logFreeSpace_mb = FILEPROPERTY(name, 'SpaceUsed')/128 FROM sys.database_files WHERE type_desc = 'LOG'

-- Calculate growth amount in MB
SET @logIncrementPercent = @logSizeMB * 0.20

IF (@logFreeSpace_mb < (@logSizeMB * 0.10))
BEGIN
    SET @newSize = @logSizeMB + @logIncrementPercent
    -- Error below: Incorrect syntax near '@newSize'. Expecting ID, Integer, QUOTED_ID, String OR TEXT_LEX
    ALTER DATABASE [AdventureWorks2019] MODIFY FILE (NAME = N'AdventureWorks2019_log', SIZE = @newSize)
END
```

I get Incorrect syntax near '@newSize' error while assigning a variable @newSize to SIZE. Everything is fine when using a number e.g. 1024, as written below:

`ALTER DATABASE [AdventureWorks2019] MODIFY FILE (NAME = N'AdventureWorks2019_log', SIZE = 1024)`

How to resolve that problem, not using dynamic SQL?

Comment: I *assume* your database is using the full recovery model? How often are you doing transaction log backups? 300GB seems like you either aren't doing them often, or you're doing some kind of *very* large operation that is causing the log to get *very* large.

Comment: The reason for the error, however, is because parameters for the `ALTER` command [*must* be literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-file-and-filegroup-options?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: _"I want to automatically manage the transaction log file size with a job to prevent it from expanding automatically during peak hours."_ - this is exactly the **wrong way** to deal with this problem. As the others have said, it means you aren't doing backups correctly because whenever a backup is done the log will be truncated to zero automatically. Don't try to "prevent" the log growing: _that's meant to happen_ (and don't think `SHRINKFILE` will help you either: that only works with a defragmented log file, which I doubt yours is...)

Comment: I use the full recovery model, transaction log backup is done every 15 minutes, database is over 1 TB. It is a good approach to increase the transaction log file size proactively before it runs out of free space.

Comment: And it's getting to 300GB in 15 minutes consistently? Perhaps you need to do more regular backups. Though it sounds more like my latter suggestion, and you're doing something that is causing a large amount of information to be "dumped" into the log.

Comment: Sounds kinda weird. isn't it better to just let it grow and shrink it down if it gets you into trouble

Comment: I agree, you should investigate the cause of the growth. 300GB in 15 minutes is abnormal even on a very large database. Perhaps you need to switch to bulk-logged, and use bulk-copy procedures to load data in. Either way, looks like the `SIZE` parameter cannot use a variable.

Comment: are you sure your backups actually run every 15 minutes? you can use: select log_reuse_wait_desc,* from sys.databases to see if there's some transaction that prevents log reuse

Answer (score 0):

I have not found a solution to resolve the problem without using dynamic SQL. As [Thom A](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2029983/thom-a) wrote, the ALTER DATABASE statement does not support using variables directly for the SIZE parameter (only literals are possible).

The only solution is using dynamic SQL.

```
DECLARE @logSizeMB INT
DECLARE @logFreeSpace_mb INT
DECLARE @logIncrementPercent INT
DECLARE @newSize INT
DECLARE @sqlCmd NVARCHAR(MAX)

-- Get current size in MB
SELECT @logSizeMB = size/128 FROM sys.database_files WHERE type_desc = 'LOG'

-- Get free space  in MB
SELECT @logFreeSpace_mb = FILEPROPERTY(name, 'SpaceUsed')/128 FROM sys.database_files WHERE type_desc = 'LOG'

-- Calculate growth amount in MB
SET @logIncrementPercent = @logSizeMB * 0.20

IF (@logFreeSpace_mb < (@logSizeMB * 0.10))
BEGIN
    SET @newSize = @logSizeMB + @logIncrementPercent
    SET @sqlCmd = N'ALTER DATABASE [AdventureWorks2019] MODIFY FILE (NAME = N''AdventureWorks2019_log'', SIZE = ' + CAST(@newSize AS NVARCHAR(10)) + N')'

    -- Execute dynamic command
    EXEC sp_executesql @sqlCmd
END
```